# AWS lambda execution fails only first time I run it with 'customer function error'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I trigger a lambda function via API gateway and everything works perfectly with the one exception that the very first time I trigger it on a given day it fails.

Strangely, the lambda function logs don't show any errors. I get my usual `START` log statement and then the request and context of the trigger, then after 5s, it ends unexpectedly.

When I look into the API gateway logs this is the error it returns:

> Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: 2018-12-10T11:00:31.208Z cc233168-fc9n-11fc-a05a-577bb4sd2b2ccc Task timed out after 5.01 seconds.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? What is customer function error and how may I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without knowing much of the background code you are using, i would termed this a Cold Start. Cold start happens for the first request where your function has not be called for a very long time. If you notice error message says "Time Out after 5.01 seconds. which is default set. you can increase a time out.

Alternatively, you could consider reducing the impact of cold starts by reducing the length of cold starts [reference](https://hackernoon.com/im-afraid-you-re-thinking-about-aws-lambda-cold-starts-all-wrong-7d907f278a4f) :

1. by authoring your Lambda functions in a language that doesn’t incur a high cold start time — i.e. Node.js, Python, or Go
2. choose a higher memory setting for functions on the critical path of handling user requests (i.e. anything that the user would have to wait for a response from, including intermediate APIs)
3. optimizing your function’s dependencies, and package size

You can also explore by putting a cron job through Cloud Watch after every specific interval to call your API through PING

Comment: Any other reasons? I'm seeing this during load testing and only after a few minutes so I seriously doubt it's due to cold starts (unless it's the cold start of the newly-scaled Lambdas).

Comment: Note: if you're using serverless framework to deploy Lambdas then the default timeout is 6 seconds, so you'll see "Task timed out after 6.01 seconds." in API Gateway logs.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Yash's answer:

I've only seen `Lambda execution failed with status 200` in API Gateway ***execution*** logs, though in case it can manifest in other ways: ensure you have execution logging enabled for the endpoint. If you didn't already have it enabled you'll need to wait for the problem to manifest again.

You can verify it's a cold start problem as follows:

- In the log entry with the error grab the `@logStream` value and the timestamp for the event; it'll be a long string of alphanumerics like `a4f8115980dc83a511eeedc493a78741`
- Open the log group for that endpoint's execution log -> find the log stream with the identifier you just grabbed
- Narrow the date/time range to a window around the time where the event occurred
- If you chose a narrow window and if it's a cold start problem: I would expect the offending request to be the first one in the list. Click the `There are older events to load. Load more.` at the top of the list.
- You should now see a gap of time between the last request received and the offending request.

In my case the error says `connection reset by peer` which leads me to think it's behaving as though a virtual machine were put to sleep then awoken in the sense that it believes TCP connections it previously had open are still valid.

In the short term the solution we're going with is to implement a retry strategy.

---

Besides the cold-start problem, there's another potential aspect of this problem: your API Gateway access log format.

Do the following:

- Find the ***access*** log entries that correspond to the offending request in the ***execution*** log.
- Is the HTTP status == `502`?

[502s in the API Gateway access log](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/malformed-502-api-gateway) usually (always?) indicate the Lambda responded with malformed JSON.

The most obvious reason for it returning malformed JSON is a bug in your code. One of the less obvious reasons: a mistake in the access log format.

If you suspect that's the case, look for the following:

- Quoted fields that shouldn't be; eg `$context.error.messageString`
- Un-quoted fields that should be. A common idiom is to leave numeric fields un-quoted because it makes `insights` queries like this work: `| filter @status >= 500`. As convenient as that is, if the field isn't guaranteed to produce a numeric result then the JSON response will be malformed.
- Trailing commas in {} bodies

[Here's the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference) for many of the the context variables, though one thing to keep in mind: the context variables that are available differ between the different API Gateway endpoint types (lambda, websocket, etc).